# how can i cover 100% of the screen using a variable ammount inline-block divs?

Tags: html, css

I have some divs which should have a min-width and a max-width, and are also inline-block and should cover 100% of the screen always.
The problem is, I'm not sure what to specify in the width part to make the divs always cover the 100%

for example, if I had 5 divs with a max width of 400 and min width of 300 covering 20% of the screen each, when I get to 1500px screen, one div should go down but the other divs should stay at 300px. I know it's because I specified the width to be 20%, but I can't find out what to do to make them automatically grow to cover the 100%

when the screen gets to 1500px, I need the divs to be 375px each, which means they should be 25% of the total width, until the screen gets to 1200px, and then repeat.

I'm trying not to use media queries, but if there´s no other way, then I think I should.

```
        <style>
          div{display:inline-block; max-width:400px; min-width:300px; width:20%; height:100px;}
        </style>
        <div style="background:red;">
        </div><!--
      --><div style="background:blue;">
        </div><!--
      --><div style="background:yellow;">
        </div><!--
      --><div style="background:magenta;">
        </div><!--
      --><div style="background:green;">
        </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: check out [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: Thanks, i was expecting someone to say that. I don´t like flexbox much, but i guess is better than using lots of media queries.

Comment: Well, if you have a device-width sensitive layout where specific widths should trigger a reflow, then you'll have to use media queries regardless.

Comment: Do you have a number for the amount of divs? say how many wide and how many high? If you do then `width=<?php echo $columns_wide / 100.'%'; ?>` should work for width. But it would be better to do that with JS, as js would have access to the window properties (for things like height & resizing).

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzBBEa

Comment: @MichaelCoker almost! i need the bottom divs to have the same width than the top ones when resize, but works! just gotta change it a bit :)

Comment: @Paulo you bet. submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` on the parent and on the children set `flex-grow: 1; flex-basis: 20%` (or `flex: 1 0 20%;` for short) so they'll "grow" to fill the parent width and have a base width of 20%, then specify  `min/max-width`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 1em;
  background: #222;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```